# How to create checkbox automatic from ajax call (Undefined currently)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Hi I needed some help on making it to auto create a checkbox to my ajax name how can i do it ? I have added the new answer to my code however currently i showing Undefinted with checkbox of the type i realize

```
<div id="modal">
<section>
<div id="recyclable_id"></div>
</section>
</div>
```

Ajax call sample for options

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
                    $.ajax( {
                        url: 'https://ecoexchange.dscloud.me:8090/api/get', 
                        type: 'GET', 
                        dataType: 'json',
                        headers:{
                            query: "RecyclableTypeGet()",
                            // Gets the apikey from the sessionStorage
                            apikey: sessionStorage.getItem("apikey")
                        },
                        success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        var html='';
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            html +='<input type="checkbox" name="recyclable_id[]" value="'+value.RecyclableID+'"><label style="padding-left: 10px;">'+value.Name+'</label><br>';
                        }
                        );
                        $('#recyclable_id').html(html);
                        }
                    }
                    );
                    }

                    );
```

this is my json response that i am going to use for the name only

```
[
    {
        "RecyclableID": 1,
        "Name": "recyclable",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 3,
        "Name": "test recyclable 2",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 129,
        "Name": "test recyclable 4",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 131,
        "Name": "test recyclable 6",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 132,
        "Name": "test recyclable 7",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 133,
        "Name": "test recyclable 8",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 134,
        "Name": "test recyclable 34",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 138,
        "Name": "recyclable thing",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 139,
        "Name": "recyclable thing 2",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 153,
        "Name": "test recyclable 10",
        "RecyclableType": "Other"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 154,
        "Name": "test recyclable 11",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 155,
        "Name": "test recyclable 123",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type 2"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 159,
        "Name": "some recyclable name",
        "RecyclableType": "CC"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 161,
        "Name": "some recyclable name 2",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaste"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 162,
        "Name": "recyclable 2",
        "RecyclableType": "test recyclable type 2"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 165,
        "Name": "test recyclable 15",
        "RecyclableType": "WASTE"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 166,
        "Name": "test recyclable 18",
        "RecyclableType": "testing type"
    },
    {
        "RecyclableID": 167,
        "Name": "some recyclable name 23",
        "RecyclableType": "Ewaster"
    }
]
```

This is my picture showing undefined [image]
I have try to change with the new anser given but it seem to be getting undefinied x 10 from type

Comment: Do a `console.log(value)` within your loop, this will tell you exactly what you're missing and if there is a value.Name index.

Comment: Thanks oh well weird is calling my other ajax call again ? hmmmm

Comment: How is console.log() making an ajax call?

Comment: OHHHH is working now ..............i realize my query call wrongly is calling the same type for my select option one .... omg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work? ***Copilot created the code xD***

```css
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax( {
    url: 'http://localhost/recyclable/public/api/recyclable', type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      var html='';
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        html +='<input type="checkbox" name="recyclable_id[]" value="'+value.RecyclableID+'"><label style="padding-left: 10px;">'+value.Name+'</label><br>';
      }
      );
      $('#recyclable_id').html(html);
    }
  }
  );
}

);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="recyclable_id"></div>
```

Comment: i got undefined through

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
url: "../Service.asmx/GetSales",

    success: function (response) {
    var result = response.d;
    var dt = $.parseXML(result);
    var serrows = '';
$.each(dt, function(key, value) {
        html +='<input type="checkbox" name="recyclable_id[]" value="'+value.RecyclableID+'"><label style="padding-left: 10px;">'+value.Name+'</label><br>';
      }

})
```